# How to pass parameter in Laravel model relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

I made a category tree and I need to pass one parameter to relation, I can't pass them.

```
public function Child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

but I want to use variable to pass in relation look like this.

```
public function Child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->where(['owner_id' => $this->ownerId]);
}
```

then I try to use variable and receive nothing, but if I use hardcoded value then works well. Please help

Comment: Is your column actually called `ownerId` or is it `owner_id` too?

Comment: no, i has this parameter in my model, but i set value after call this relation

Comment: I don't think this will be possible then. You're probably going to have to leave the relationship without a `where` clause, and then create a query scope with your condition and variable.

Answer (score 7):

```php
$models = App\{YourMainModel}::with(['Child' => function ($query) use ($this) {
    $query->where(['owner_id' => $this->ownerId]);
}])->get();
```

Comment: not working in my case. I use two relations for get all children models.

Comment: You can read more about it by link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add a constructor to your Child model (which extends the class Model).

```
private ownerId;

public function __construct(int ownerId)
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->ownerId = $ownerId;
}
```

Then you can access this throughout your class.

```
public function child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->where('owner_id', $this->ownerId);
}
```

You would do this if every time you wanted to instantiate your class Child, you would have to give it an owner:

```
$ownerId = 5;
$child = new Child($ownerId);
```

Alternatively, you could pass a parameter directly to that function from wherever you call it, like:

```
public function childWithOwner(int $ownerId)
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->where('owner_id', $ownerId);
}
```

And you would call it: `$this->childWithOwner(4);`

As a tip I would encourage you to start your function names with a lowercase letter.